Do all Physocyclus globosus have pedipalps?
While browsing photos of Physocyclus globosus (short-bodied cellar spider) on iNaturalist, I noticed that some have pedipalps while others does not, they are not Physocyclus globosus or not all Physocyclus globosus have pedipalps?
(If you didn't know, here's a picture of a (presumed) Physocyclus globosus, see pedipalps?)

(photographed by me, CC0 waiver)

Welcome Stkimension. I'm not clear what you're referring to when you say "eye humps". Could you be referring to the pedipalps or chelicerae? Perhaps something else?

I mean pedipalps

Just readed the Wikipedia article, seems like only male one have pedipalpsEdit: wait some female have too

The type reference doesn't say anything about differences between male and female in the species. The 1893 revision into Physocyclus might say something

All arachnids have pedipalps (males, females, spiders, harvestmen, scorpions, pseudoscorpions, tarantulas, ticks, solifuges, etc). Pedipalps are part of their basic anatomy. In scorpions and pseudoscorpions the pedipals are the pincers/claws.
As mentioned in the other response, the male pedipals of spiders typically have enlarged ends for holding sperm, and so they are more noticeable. And the pedipalp size is often used to separate the sex of mature spiders for many species.
Further, the shape of the sexual organs (palps for males and the female epigynum) are observed with microscopic examination for species identification in most spider species.

In general, female spiders have small pedipalps with no enlargement on the ends, whereas males have larger ends tufted with hair for carrying sperm during mating, and sometimes, for display.  Maybe you aren't seeing the ones on the females because they are very small?  Not an expert here, but pretty good with invert zoo in general. Anyone else?

Original research: So turn out the one with bigger eyes thing have moulted more times (not just older but also they have to catch  enough preys as i seen a Physocyclus Globosus daughter moulted much sooner than her mother, but after some months the mother catched a huge prey and moulted just a day after that)
Sorry i can't upload the photo i took because i don't want to be doxxed but i've collected some moulted skin and will took a photo of it soon
thanks everyone
edit 20241103
WAIT no the one with bigger "eyes", longer legs and smaller abdomen are male
